# Connection closed before full header was received

Tags: flutter

I'm new with flutter and I'm working on an app that show a long listView of images via Image.network.
All is running, but quite often and absolutely random (even if I scroll very slowly), I get this error:

```
I/flutter (10990): EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE 
I/flutter (10990): The following HttpException was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter (10990): Connection closed before full header was received, uri =
I/flutter (10990): http://www.attilofficina.altervista.org/phpbackend/JOB/000004/mockup/000004_017.jpg
I/flutter (10990): 
I/flutter (10990): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (10990): #0      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:525:41)
I/flutter (10990): <asynchronous suspension>.
```

And those images are skipped!

Is there a way to handle this error and force reload of those images missing?
Special thanks in advance

I've also tried with paginated `listView`, with minimum number of pages to be load at a time, but this doesn't solve and the error always returns randomly.

Here flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.3, on Microsoft Windows [Versione 10.0.17134.885], locale it-IT)
    • Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.3 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision b712a172f9 (7 days ago), 2019-07-09 13:14:38 -0700
    • Engine revision 54ad777fd2
    • Dart version 2.4.0


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Mussa.DESKTOP-HFFLS0G\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 37.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.36.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Mussa.DESKTOP-HFFLS0G\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.2.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android P (API 27) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: Absolutely yes, I've added it upon.
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was having exactly the same issue and was never able to figure out the cause of the issue.
I ended up using the [Cached network image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) library which fixed my problems with image loading.

Comment: special thanks Jakub, also for me Cached network image library fixed my problems with image loading and all now works absolutely fine!!! great!

Comment: I have used this small hack :) https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25107#issuecomment-655655719

Comment: This library has the same problem. I haven't been able to deduce the root cause.

Comment: Same issue is with Cached Network Image

Comment: Don't know why this is accepted answer. It does not work. Answer by @Till works

Answer (score 19):

It may be because the widget is reused in the widget tree and thus interrupts the HTTP request. You could then use a key in your FutureBuilder or Image widget.

```dart
child: FutureBuilder<File>(
  key: ValueKey(imageUrl), // or use UniqueKey()  
  ...
```

Comment: Just the valuekey worked for me.

Comment: YOU ROCK! WISHED I CAME TO REPLY EARLIER

Comment: this solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

This issue still exists even though the [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25107) was closed:

This error really random and we couldn't know when it will become an error.

My solution to fix this issue is we can use FadeInImage to know when is the request image got the error `Connection closed before full header was received, URI =` we can handle it on `imageErrorBuilder` method.

I create a new Widget called UrlImage:

```html
FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
      placeholder: kTransparentImage,
      image: imageURL,
      imageErrorBuilder: (context, error, stacktrace) { // Handle Error for the 1st time
        return FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
          placeholder: kTransparentImage,
          image: imageURL,
          imageErrorBuilder: (context, error, stacktrace) { // Handle Error for the 2nd time
            return FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              placeholder: kTransparentImage,
              image: imageURL,
              imageErrorBuilder: (context, error, stacktrace) { // Handle Error for the 3rd time to return text
                return Center(child: Text('Image Not Available'));
              },
            );
          },
        );
```

More detail Widget, you can see the code below on my Gist:
https://gist.github.com/Robihamanto/5e0dd358d4da90603683ca74430aff8a

Comment: somehow this feels like a bandage on a bandage on a bandage. The wound(bug) is still there...

Answer (score 2):

The issue still exists as of writing this. I tried with `CachedNetworkImage` package and the result is same. Finally I ended up using `extended_image` and it works like charm. Have a look at the plugin here- https://pub.dev/packages/extended_image

I have completed ported my application to use this package. Loading, Error, Success events also can be handled easily like `CachedNetworkImage`